# iPhone #ifdef directive not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using Xcode 4 to update one of my apps that were previously developed with Xcode 3.

On one part of the code I had:

```
#define CREATE YES
```

and later...

```
#ifdef CREATE
// do stuff
#endif
```

on Xcode 3, this branch would be executed just if CREATE was yes but now in Xcode 4 it is being executed all the time.

As far as I see that Xcode 4 approach appears to be the most correct, as I am asking if the variable is defined, Xcode 3 worked somehow as I wanted.

So, now, how do I test for the boolean value of CREATE on Xcode 4?

something like:

```
#ifdef CREATE == YES
// DO STUFF
#endif
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define CREATE 1
#if CREATE
// do stuff
#else
//do other stuff
#endif
```

i think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: that's it. Thanks. I failed to see the obvious... :(

Comment: and what for #ifndef ?

Answer (score 3):

try using the #if directive instead of #ifdef

```
#define CREATE NO

#if CREATE
//This should not run.
#endif
```